# Garage door leaks

Tags: garage, garage-door

I've tried to fix the leaks my garage door has, but just can't seem to solve the issue. I tried replacing the bottom seal, as well as the side seal, both to no avail.

I added some pictures of the bottom seal (where you can see water coming in) as well as some shots of the side of the door from the inside (where you can see how the side seal aligns with the door).

The ground in the garage isn't very level, I've debated glueing a barrier seal down onto the concrete floor as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just throwing it out there.  On ours, the water comes in from the side at the bottom, instead of underneath the door.

Answer (score 28):

Garage doors are not made to be watertight.  Seeping of water from heavy or wind driven rain is normal.  If the seepage you are showing is from water running toward the door, then you need to correct that and redirect the water.

Answer (score 23):

No garage door is leak-proof. You need a slightly raised threshold outside the door to keep water from entering. If you can't raise the level of the concrete outside the door, you can try adding a threshold strip, such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RWFYSQ1), or [these](https://www.bobvila.com/articles/best-garage-door-threshold/). Water-tight sealing *underneath* the threshold is essential.

If you have an opportunity to change landscaping so that flowing water is directed away from the house, or to ensure the driveway slopes down to the street from the house, with a rise of a cm or two from driveway to garage, that's best, but not a casual DIY job.

Example

[image: example]

Comment: The right way to build the garage floor would have been to build a small step, where the door closes on the bottom step.  Then any water that makes its way under the door is contained there and doesn't go across the floor.

Comment: @Huesmann I've also seen one with a long drain just inside the door

Comment: I had a leaky garage door and this solution kept my garage dry, even with driving rain.